# TINA-TI - trouble with Digital-to-Analog Converter DAC161P997 Self-Powered Transmitter

Tags: current, simulation, dac, spice, texas-instruments

I'm dealing with the [DAC161P997](https://www.ti.com/product/DAC161P997) simulation on TINA-TI. Using the model from TI, the circuit appears to function correctly only if I leave out the capacitors on the pin.

Here's the setup – Data Generator Bit, DAC model with a self-powered transmitter.

[image: schematic DAC161P997 Self-power transmitter]

I'm generating two sequences of bits (BBAA and BCAA) with a step time of 100ms. With the circuit above, the current appears to be correct, aligning with the expected values derived from the formula.

[image]

However, when I connect the capacitors, the second sequence isn't converted correctly. Instead, the current manifests as a pulse train rather than a steady value.

[image]

Are there any errors in the schematic, or is there something else that might be causing this discrepancy?

Comment: leave out *which* capacitor on *which* pin?

Comment: where's the decoupling caps on the supply voltage?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm referring to capacitors C1, C2, and C3, which are parts of an integrated low-pass filter connected to the DAC current. I've noticed that in the figure, the DAC symbol covers the power supply VDDA, making it not visible, although it is present. For now, my aim is to conduct a basic simulation of the circuit, so I haven't connected the decoupling capacitors yet

Comment: I'd recommend you connect them now, because there's probably a reason your V1 and VS2 have different symbols, and I guess it's because V1 entails internal resistance, making the decoupling caps a necessitiy.